# Start a locally run Service and route traffic to it

Tags: asp.net, docker, kubernetes, microservices, infrastructure

I am wondering if it is possible to route traffic in a microservice environment to my local machine to debug a service.

I have a microservice architecture written with ASP.Net and published as a docker container. They all run on my HomeServer and communicate with each other via a REST Api (just to simplify things). Because I have so many microservices I dont want to start all of them locally in order to develop them further, instead I try to find a way to route traffic directly to my local machine when I start a service from my IDE.

My first idea was using a service discovery. But then a friend told me about using Rancher.

But before I will spend that much time, I wanted to ask if anyone else had this situation and need, or does know a solution for this